# Can Java 7 and Java 8 co-exist on OSX

Tags: java, macos, java-8

I've installed Java 8 for development purposes but now I'd like to use Java 7 again.

How do I do this?

It seems to be insanely difficult.

Many thanks in advance.
(I've tried using guigarage and that doesn't work)

Comment: It depends. Generally, you should just change `PATH` variable value. But when it comes to development, it depends on IDE. You should see how to switch between JDK's for your IDE.

Comment: IntellIJ won't start up at all because my default Java is Java 8.

Comment: Try to remove your current `JRE` and install `JRE 7` again.

Comment: That's what I was trying to avoid - anyway how do I remove my current JRE? (I'm new to Mac is there an uninstaller?) Thanks

Comment: Google is your friend. I'm not a Mac user. Sorry.

Comment: I can assure you I've tried my friend Google... looking for new friends.

Comment: All the VMs live here: `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines`. mac os x will pick the biggest one by default - so `java` will invoke java 1.8 by default if it's installed there. You can move it somewhere else and it should work from that location as long as you set the path manually

Comment: to fix the control panel issue, you need to reinstall java 7 - the internet plugin has been replaced by the one from java 8, which *may* cause problems.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

From a terminal: `` export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.x` ``, where x is the Java version.

I personally have a shell function that does that for me:

```
use-java () {
    export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.$1`
}
```

I just have to call `use-java 7` or `use-java 8` in order to change my current shell's Java version.

Comment: Thanks - but as I understand it that's only useful if your program uses the JAVA_HOME variable in it's start script.  What if you are launching eclipse or Intellij or something that just uses the default java on the machine.  Can you change that?

Comment: `JAVA_HOME` specifies the path of the JDK you'd be using in your terminal (for `java` or `javac` for example). It doesn't impact Java version outside of the terminal. IDEs have their own JDK versions configuration. In IntelliJ, you'd need to open the project preferences, go to the *Project* panel, and choose the JDK version you want to use.

Comment: I'm talking about actually running IntelliJ (the IDE is a Java program).

Comment: Oh sorry. That what I've understood from your question, but then I hesitated and edited it. You need to edit `<key>JVMVersion</key><string>1.7*</string>` in */Applications/IntelliJ IDEA XXX.app/Contents/Info.plist*.

Answer (score 27):

Use [jEnv](http://www.jenv.be).

If your system runs [homebrew](http://brew.sh), you can install it using

```
brew install jenv
```

(You may need to run `brew update` to get the latest recipes first)

Add it to your bash profile using

```
echo 'eval "$(jenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Start a new shell to make this change to the profile effective.

You can then add jdk’s like this:

```
jenv add /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home
```

list the available versions using

```
jenv versions
```

And switch between environments using

```
jenv global oracle64-1.8.0.25
```

There’s plenty more custom options, like switching per directory or temporarily in a single shell, see http://www.jenv.be for those.

jEnv works by creating shim scripts for the java executables and putting them in the front of the path. Some 3rd party java tools like ant and maven rely on JAVA_HOME. To make sure JAVA_HOME gets set properly, run

```
jenv enable-plugin export
```

There's also jenv plugins for tools like maven and groovy.

Comment: if use zsh, use below commands to add it to .zshrc

$ echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.jenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
$ echo 'eval "$(jenv init -)"' >> ~/.zshrc

Answer (score 5):

Here is an excellent answer for how to switch Java version from the command line in OSX Mavericks ([source](https://superuser.com/a/568016) by [Neeme Praks](https://superuser.com/users/141239/neeme-praks)):

> Edit your `~/.bash_profile` and add the following:

```
function setjdk() {  
  if [ $# -ne 0 ]; then  
   removeFromPath '/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home/bin'  
   if [ -n "${JAVA_HOME+x}" ]; then  
    removeFromPath $JAVA_HOME  
   fi  
   export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v $@`  
   export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH  
  fi  
  echo JAVA_HOME set to $JAVA_HOME  
  java -version  
 }  
 function removeFromPath() {  
  export PATH=$(echo $PATH | sed -E -e "s;:$1;;" -e "s;$1:?;;")  
 }
```

(add above function to your `.bash_profile`)

**Usage:**

```
$ setjdk 1.7
```

Answer (score 1):

After installation, open the Java Preferences (Launchapad/Others):

[image]

and drag the preferred version on top of list:

[image]

Comment: On my version of Mac (10.9.1) the screen looks slightly different.  You open it from System Preferences. It only shows my current version of Java (java 8) in the list.

Comment: Install java 7 again, and it will be added to the list.

Comment: I did that now it says that the platform is 1.8 but the product is 1.7?? java -version says 1.8.  Do you know how I delete java 8 completely from my machine?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of Java preferences dialog?